# Javascript fit fontsize to div

Tags: javascript, html, while-loop, font-size

I'm trying to fit text and images in divs, that should all have the same size. I don't know how much text there will be, but it won't be so much, that the text can't be read. When i try this, it wont stop executing the loop.
Please don't use jquery in your answers, because I'm starting to learn to code and will learn this later.

Thanks for your time :)

```
function scale (i) {
    while ( document.getElementById("A" + i).scrollHeight > document.getElementById("A" + i).clientHeight) {
        document.getElementById("A"+i).style.fontSize = "smaller";
        }
}
```

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please include all the relevant code in the form of a [example]. You've asked a question about modifying CSS and HTML with JavaScript. We need to see the CSS and HTML as well as the JavaScript. You can use [StackSnippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: Since `fontSize` is always being changed to one specific size (smaller) it may never get out of the loop. Try reading the font-size and changing it incrementally?

Comment: I think I also tried that, unfortunately I lost all my Code and now I'm to frustrated and I will continiue other projects. Regardless, thank you for your help